# Dropbox plugin cordova crash when open my app without dropbox app exist in device

Tags: cordova, dropbox

I followed this plugin : https://github.com/cv-library/phonegap-plugin-dropbox-chooser. When i launch my app and import images from Dropbox, it work well when i already have app Dropbox in device. But when devices haven't installed Dropbox app before, my app can not show message like "You must install Dropbox app first" without crash my app.
It has problem both IOS and Android,on IOS i can changed the code inside plugin so it work well, but in Android i can not change the code inside the package. Anybody got problem like this, please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use one of this solutions:

1. You can try to catch the error:

```js
try {
  // Try to access the dropbox app 
} catch (error) {
  // Do something, if fails 
}
```

2. You can check, if the dropbox app exists with this plugin (is 2 year old):

https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability/

Comment: I saw it show the error : at "com.dropbox.chooser.android.AppStoreInterstitial$NativeFragment.onCreateDialog(AppStoreInterstitial.java:53)". I think it pass the javascript and get the error when try to launch the dialog message.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by download the new DropboxSDK and import this library into my project. If someone got this problem, just downloaded the newest https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android